# Find vectors $\vec{w}, \vec{z}$ in $ℝ^4$ so that $\{\vec u, \vec v, \vec w\}$ is linearly independent but $\{\vec u, \vec v, \vec z\}$ is not

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, independence

I am given two vectors, $\vec u$ and $\vec v$. I'm not sure how to find the third vector. I know for linearly independent, the coefficients for the linear combination must all equal zero in order to get the zero vector. For linearly dependent, I know that the not all of the coefficients can equate to zero.

Original Problem:

Given the following vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, find a vector $\vec w$ in $\Bbb R^4$ so that $\{\vec u, \vec v, \vec w\}$ is linearly independent and a non-zero vector $\vec z$ in $\Bbb R^4$ so that $\{\vec u, \vec v, \vec z\}$ is linearly dependent:

$$\vec u=\begin{bmatrix}-9\\-1\\-1\\4\end{bmatrix}
\quad\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}5\\10\\-8\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\vec w=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\quad\vec z=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The second question is easier. The answer exploits the fact that every set containing at least a vector and the zero vector is linearly dependent. Alternatively, you can solve it simply choosing two scalars $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ so that $z=\alpha u+ \beta v$.

As to the first one, the formal way would be use the definition of linear independence and go through a linear system in four equations. Nonetheless with a bit of logic you can easily solve it without using any kind of computation. For example, if you call $w=(3,3,0,0)$ the set will still be linearly independent. Why? Try to think about the linear combinations of the first two components of the vectors $v,u$. Can you find two scalars such that their linear combination with the first two components of the vectors $v,u$ gives you back the first two components of the vector $w$? In this way you can construct as many example as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use orthogonal-triangular decomposition (also called QR decomposition). If **u** and **v** are column vectors of length **N**, then the MATLAB statement

> [Q,R] = qr([u,v] )

returns an **N** x **N** orthonormal matrix **Q** and an upper triangular **N** x 2 matrix **R**. The first two columns of **Q** are vectors that span the subspace of **u** and **v**. So any linear combination of those two vectors are linearly dependent on **u** and **v**. The remaining **N-2** columns of **Q** are orthogonal to **u** and **v**. So any linear combination of those **N-2** vectors are linearly independent of **u** and **v**. This works for **N**>2.